# Is chess with pawn odds still a draw?

Tags: draw, odds

[Virtually everyone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-move_advantage_in_chess#Drawn_with_best_play) believes chess from the starting position is a draw, and the result is borne out at top level - at the ICCF correspondence chess world chess championships, [almost every game is drawn](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/5158/are-world-class-correspondence-games-more-likely-to-be-drawn-than-world-class-ot/31574#31574).

Is there any evidence that chess at pawn odds is or is not a draw?

I'm interested in all variants of pawn odds - so e.g. White starts without the a2-pawn, the b2-pawn, etc., and also Black starts without the a7-pawn, b7-pawn, etc. As far as I know starting without the f2 or f7-pawn is the largest handicap. If this is still drawn, then the other pawn odds are probably drawn too.

Comment: I would be very surprised if Black could hold with pawn odds. For White, I could see it for the less important pawns, like without the a2 pawn maybe White can hold. But in general, a pawn is quite a lot if there is no compensation.

Comment: Looking at Leelas evaluation as a very rough approximation, it agrees with my assessment that for Black it would be hard to draw, for White even with the f or e pawn gone it still gives White significant drawing chances. Now Leela isn't made for this of course, but if one were to take the results at face value it might be a close call. With a2 pawn odds indeed it looks like White should still hold.

Comment: @koedem what opening evals do you get, and at what depth?

Comment: I did my analyses with a recent 40 block network, I only looked relatively briefly at most positions but e.g. for h7 missing I did a deeper search of now roughly 10 million nodes. The evaluation is around 75% (with variation 1.Nf3 Nc6 2.d4 d5 3.Bf4) and so forth.
a7 missing looks to be a similar eval, the rest is all much worse for Black so presumably losing.

Comment: On a more general note, I like the opening variety in those different positions. Maybe this is the future of classical chess, 2 game mini matches with a random pawn odds. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run sf14.1 engine at TC 10m+5s.

**Black pawn odds**
There are 8 positions, black has no pawn at a, b ... h.

```
Score of Stockfish 14.1 white vs Stockfish 14.1 black: 8 - 0 - 0 [1.000]
...      Stockfish 14.1 white playing White: 8 - 0 - 0  [1.000] 8
...      White vs Black: 8 - 0 - 0  [1.000] 8
Elo difference: inf +/- nan, LOS: 99.8 %, DrawRatio: 0.0 %
8 of 8 games finished.
```

*Sample games*

```
[Event "?"]
[Site "?"]
[Date "2022.03.19"]
[Round "1"]
[White "Stockfish 14.1 white"]
[Black "Stockfish 14.1 black"]
[Result "1-0"]
[FEN "rnbqkbnr/1ppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1"]
[GameDuration "00:34:11"]
[PlyCount "178"]
[SetUp "1"]
[Termination "adjudication"]
[TimeControl "600+5"]

1. d4 {+1.63/29 28.20s} Nf6 {-1.55/26 14.34s} 2. Nf3 {+1.74/26 6.24s}
g6 {-1.54/30 18.33s} 3. e3 {+1.59/28 12.15s} Bg7 {-1.59/28 12.63s}
4. Be2 {+1.66/25 9.66s} O-O {-1.62/28 12.61s} 5. O-O {+1.72/25 11.56s}
d5 {-1.64/26 20.27s} 6. b3 {+1.78/26 11.13s} Ne4 {-1.55/28 13.58s}
7. Bb2 {+1.60/30 18.39s} c5 {-1.56/28 11.30s} 8. a4 {+1.71/26 9.79s}
Nc6 {-1.62/27 12.46s} 9. Na3 {+1.81/27 13.64s} Bf5 {-1.46/25 11.90s}
10. Nb5 {+1.87/25 11.58s} h5 {-1.59/26 14.45s} 11. c4 {+1.82/26 29.30s}
dxc4 {-1.65/24 13.45s} 12. Bxc4 {+1.82/26 8.11s} Nd6 {-1.55/25 11.90s}
13. Nxd6 {+1.78/28 40.03s} exd6 {-1.67/26 16.18s} 14. Rc1 {+2.10/30 81.19s}
g5 {-1.74/28 38.65s} 15. Bd3 {+1.81/27 11.60s} Bxd3 {-1.43/25 7.81s}
16. Qxd3 {+1.85/28 16.71s} g4 {-1.59/29 21.60s} 17. Nd2 {+1.75/29 13.60s}
Re8 {-1.58/28 11.68s} 18. Nc4 {+1.67/31 55.15s} cxd4 {-1.53/27 11.22s}
19. exd4 {+1.72/27 8.32s} d5 {-1.54/27 12.42s} 20. Ne3 {+1.80/30 14.78s}
Qg5 {-1.44/29 22.67s} 21. Rfd1 {+1.53/31 83.68s} Rad8 {-1.56/28 18.00s}
22. Qf5 {+1.48/28 8.36s} Qxf5 {-1.61/30 19.02s} 23. Nxf5 {+1.45/27 9.03s}
Re2 {-1.76/30 14.32s} 24. Bc3 {+1.50/30 33.45s} Ra2 {-1.28/27 11.24s}
25. Ra1 {+1.64/28 5.65s} Rc2 {-1.36/31 22.98s} 26. Nxg7 {+1.51/29 11.09s}
Kxg7 {-1.40/31 18.93s} 27. Rdc1 {+1.78/27 7.89s} Rxc1+ {-1.41/30 13.00s}
28. Rxc1 {+1.53/31 23.63s} Rc8 {-1.44/34 51.37s} 29. Bd2 {+1.36/34 45.74s}
Kf6 {-1.44/34 22.09s} 30. Rc5 {+1.45/33 20.91s} Ke6 {-1.34/28 7.28s}
31. Kf1 {+1.30/29 5.52s} b6 {-1.27/30 19.91s} 32. Rc3 {+1.44/29 11.96s}
Kd7 {-1.47/32 36.47s} 33. f3 {+1.61/27 9.52s} f5 {-1.44/28 7.88s}
34. Kf2 {+1.58/30 11.33s} Rg8 {-1.43/27 12.86s} 35. h4 {+1.58/26 7.40s}
gxh3 {-1.32/32 63.21s} 36. gxh3 {+1.70/29 8.27s} h4 {-1.59/32 9.31s}
37. Bf4 {+1.53/30 9.45s} Rg6 {-1.52/31 12.95s} 38. Kf1 {+1.61/30 6.20s}
Rf6 {-1.39/31 21.45s} 39. Bg5 {+1.63/33 29.02s} Rf7 {-1.41/30 7.03s}
40. Kf2 {+1.65/29 2.88s} Rg7 {-1.59/31 10.20s} 41. Be3 {+1.49/31 7.97s}
Nd8 {-1.82/29 14.56s} 42. Bf4 {+1.78/27 5.47s} Ne6 {-1.87/31 9.82s}
43. Be5 {+1.88/26 4.53s} Rg8 {-1.54/33 11.62s} 44. b4 {+1.74/28 6.29s}
Ra8 {-1.56/30 8.61s} 45. Ra3 {+2.00/25 3.75s} Ng5 {-1.41/28 7.22s}
46. Kf1 {+1.86/26 8.29s} Ne6 {-1.38/28 11.00s} 47. Bf6 {+1.90/28 8.34s}
Nf4 {-1.61/31 9.94s} 48. Bxh4 {+1.95/25 2.42s} Nxh3 {-1.67/31 7.53s}
49. Bf6 {+1.87/28 3.69s} Nf4 {-1.75/29 5.36s} 50. Kf2 {+2.00/26 3.85s}
Ng6 {-1.70/31 31.05s} 51. Kg3 {+2.04/30 11.40s} Rf8 {-1.75/29 2.41s}
52. Bg5 {+1.98/29 3.49s} Rg8 {-1.68/30 2.93s} 53. Kf2 {+1.92/29 9.81s}
Nf8 {-1.87/30 4.88s} 54. Bf6 {+1.87/29 5.04s} Ng6 {-1.56/30 3.81s}
55. a5 {+1.71/30 4.87s} Ra8 {-1.71/31 5.22s} 56. Kg3 {+1.85/29 3.64s}
Kc6 {-1.95/31 5.71s} 57. Be5 {+1.74/31 6.48s} Kb7 {-1.99/29 3.36s}
58. Ra2 {+1.91/26 4.61s} Ra7 {-1.95/29 7.67s} 59. Bd6 {+1.87/26 3.52s}
Kc6 {-2.25/32 14.51s} 60. Bb8 {+2.04/25 3.45s} Ra8 {-2.24/32 12.58s}
61. Rc2+ {+1.97/25 4.05s} Kb7 {-2.22/30 2.64s} 62. Bd6 {+2.70/23 4.57s}
Rg8 {-2.57/27 3.10s} 63. axb6 {+3.24/24 3.81s} Kxb6 {-3.07/24 5.97s}
64. Rc3 {+3.29/24 3.37s} Ka6 {-3.30/26 13.94s} 65. Rc6+ {+3.50/25 5.06s}
Kb7 {-3.53/23 0.87s} 66. Rc5 {+3.35/26 5.36s} Ne5+ {-3.30/25 11.79s}
67. Kf4 {+3.71/26 5.80s} Ng6+ {-3.44/23 0.71s} 68. Kg5 {+3.71/27 8.80s}
Ne5+ {-3.50/23 2.21s} 69. Kf4 {+3.63/28 3.12s} Ng6+ {-3.58/25 1.57s}
70. Kxf5 {+3.53/26 4.76s} Nh4+ {-3.54/25 2.55s} 71. Kf4 {+3.95/25 3.90s}
Rd8 {-3.75/26 5.25s} 72. Bc7 {+4.00/25 4.05s} Rf8+ {-4.00/26 9.08s}
73. Ke5 {+4.00/26 3.37s} Nxf3+ {-3.84/24 1.21s} 74. Kxd5 {+4.00/25 4.16s}
Rg8 {-4.05/27 11.90s} 75. Be5 {+4.09/24 4.17s} Rd8+ {-4.14/29 10.44s}
76. Ke6 {+4.50/27 10.37s} Re8+ {-4.66/26 6.41s} 77. Kd7 {+4.75/23 3.40s}
Rg8 {-4.70/22 1.78s} 78. Rc3 {+4.84/25 3.63s} Rf8 {-5.00/21 1.62s}
79. Ke7 {+5.19/27 4.02s} Rf5 {-5.04/23 1.94s} 80. Ke6 {+5.42/26 3.61s}
Rf8 {-5.04/23 1.70s} 81. Bf6 {+5.57/26 3.82s} Nd2 {-5.37/25 3.15s}
82. Rd3 {+5.74/24 3.65s} Ne4 {-5.61/25 6.98s} 83. Be7 {+6.15/27 6.64s}
Nf2 {-6.09/29 9.25s} 84. Re3 {+6.52/23 7.54s} Rh8 {-5.92/19 1.34s}
85. d5 {+6.67/22 2.98s} Rh6+ {-6.98/23 13.59s} 86. Kd7 {+6.94/22 4.05s}
Ng4 {-6.89/22 6.08s} 87. Re4 {+7.08/22 4.20s} Nf6+ {-6.58/22 4.08s}
88. Bxf6 {+9.09/22 4.24s} Rxf6 {-10.46/24 8.06s} 89. d6 {+9.51/20 4.60s}
Rh6 {-14.73/19 4.96s, White wins by adjudication} 1-0
```

```
[Event "?"]
[Site "?"]
[Date "2022.03.19"]
[Round "2"]
[White "Stockfish 14.1 white"]
[Black "Stockfish 14.1 black"]
[Result "1-0"]
[FEN "rnbqkbnr/p1pppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1"]
[GameDuration "00:31:22"]
[PlyCount "142"]
[SetUp "1"]
[Termination "adjudication"]
[TimeControl "600+5"]

1. d4 {+2.31/28 25.15s} Nf6 {-2.15/29 56.13s} 2. c4 {+2.18/29 33.49s}
e6 {-2.18/26 4.89s} 3. e3 {+2.32/25 5.32s} Bb4+ {-2.13/29 44.53s}
4. Bd2 {+2.31/27 22.40s} Bxd2+ {-2.31/26 10.60s} 5. Qxd2 {+2.01/27 12.92s}
c5 {-2.38/27 16.99s} 6. Nf3 {+2.35/27 16.90s} Ne4 {-2.21/26 11.25s}
7. Qd3 {+2.27/27 11.82s} f5 {-2.12/27 33.89s} 8. Be2 {+2.24/25 13.15s}
Na6 {-2.31/24 9.98s} 9. Nc3 {+2.55/26 16.41s} Rb8 {-2.48/29 11.80s}
10. Rb1 {+2.66/28 14.26s} Nb4 {-2.48/30 10.17s} 11. Qd1 {+2.43/31 22.25s}
cxd4 {-2.30/28 18.51s} 12. exd4 {+2.22/32 27.97s} Qa5 {-2.23/30 12.94s}
13. O-O {+2.16/31 17.09s} Nxa2 {-1.96/29 13.45s} 14. Nxe4 {+2.18/31 14.76s}
fxe4 {-2.35/31 25.49s} 15. Ne5 {+2.17/30 13.24s} O-O {-2.22/32 28.97s}
16. Qc2 {+2.57/32 37.59s} d6 {-2.35/28 16.18s} 17. Nc6 {+2.61/26 9.35s}
Nb4 {-2.37/29 15.30s} 18. Qxe4 {+2.56/30 15.76s} Nxc6 {-2.31/29 16.77s}
19. Qxc6 {+2.57/30 15.23s} d5 {-2.31/30 14.33s} 20. b3 {+2.55/30 25.13s}
Qa2 {-2.35/31 15.64s} 21. Bf3 {+2.21/28 15.22s} Rb6 {-2.21/30 11.44s}
22. Qc7 {+2.42/30 15.54s} Rxb3 {-2.18/33 13.33s} 23. Ra1 {+2.34/31 21.24s}
Qb2 {-2.15/30 11.91s} 24. cxd5 {+2.56/33 31.64s} Qxd4 {-2.32/32 29.75s}
25. Rxa7 {+2.35/30 12.68s} Rc3 {-2.29/29 12.57s} 26. Qe7 {+2.35/30 10.03s}
Qf6 {-2.35/30 13.51s} 27. Qxf6 {+2.30/29 16.91s} gxf6 {-2.40/33 9.73s}
28. h3 {+2.33/29 13.64s} Rf7 {-2.42/28 11.48s} 29. Raa1 {+2.22/32 21.23s}
e5 {-2.42/31 10.46s} 30. Rfc1 {+2.66/31 12.90s} Rxc1+ {-2.43/32 9.41s}
31. Rxc1 {+2.70/33 18.69s} Rf8 {-2.58/33 16.87s} 32. Kh2 {+2.42/30 9.84s}
Bf5 {-2.35/33 23.23s} 33. g4 {+2.53/32 25.32s} Bg6 {-2.13/27 8.89s}
34. Rc6 {+2.69/29 8.64s} Rd8 {-2.34/32 29.04s} 35. h4 {+2.67/32 17.82s}
Kg7 {-2.34/30 8.71s} 36. d6 {+2.45/31 14.42s} Be8 {-2.26/33 20.51s}
37. Rc7+ {+2.50/33 8.71s} Kf8 {-2.36/32 8.71s} 38. Rxh7 {+2.47/35 9.41s}
Rxd6 {-2.26/36 9.04s} 39. h5 {+2.45/36 9.32s} Rd4 {-2.18/35 8.50s}
40. h6 {+2.25/36 16.20s} Kg8 {-2.17/34 9.18s} 41. Rg7+ {+2.46/34 8.79s}
Kh8 {-2.18/39 13.18s} 42. Bb7 {+2.53/39 9.27s} Ba4 {-2.25/34 8.60s}
43. Kh3 {+2.77/40 10.04s} Bc2 {-2.11/37 9.76s} 44. Rf7 {+3.40/32 8.76s}
Rd6 {-2.14/37 14.89s} 45. f3 {+3.50/33 13.81s} Bg6 {-2.13/36 13.64s}
46. Re7 {+3.58/32 12.42s} Rd8 {-1.97/35 8.05s} 47. Kg3 {+3.99/29 8.26s}
Rf8 {-3.38/34 24.70s} 48. Bd5 {+3.99/31 9.08s} Rd8 {-3.41/33 9.52s}
49. Bb3 {+3.96/32 8.24s} Rb8 {-3.18/33 14.96s} 50. Bc4 {+4.03/36 25.11s}
Rb6 {-3.60/34 18.32s} 51. Rd7 {+4.12/32 4.83s} Bc2 {-3.36/34 5.33s}
52. Bd5 {+4.13/34 5.73s} Ra6 {-3.69/33 13.67s} 53. Bb7 {+4.24/34 5.70s}
Rb6 {-3.12/31 5.24s} 54. Ba8 {+4.29/35 7.86s} Ra6 {-4.83/35 36.83s}
55. Bd5 {+4.39/38 12.21s} Rb6 {-4.83/31 1.44s} 56. Kh4 {+4.60/30 4.63s}
Rb1 {-4.83/30 2.61s} 57. f4 {+4.76/28 5.82s} exf4 {-4.84/29 2.60s}
58. Rc7 {+4.84/27 4.88s} Bg6 {-4.86/29 3.44s} 59. Rc6 {+4.97/27 5.92s}
f3 {-4.87/27 3.21s} 60. Bxf3 {+5.10/28 5.87s} Kh7 {-5.06/34 7.31s}
61. Rxf6 {+5.18/28 4.45s} Re1 {-5.27/28 6.99s} 62. g5 {+5.18/30 6.67s}
Ra1 {-5.61/25 6.24s} 63. Re6 {+5.26/25 5.36s} Ra4+ {-5.93/21 4.45s}
64. Kg3 {+5.48/24 4.98s} Bb1 {-6.34/29 10.87s} 65. Bc6 {+7.28/23 5.17s}
Rc4 {-6.35/28 1.39s} 66. Kf3 {+8.01/23 6.67s} Rc1 {-7.82/22 6.55s}
67. Kg4 {+8.20/26 5.21s} Rc4+ {-7.80/19 3.15s} 68. Kh5 {+8.33/27 6.60s}
Bc2 {-8.31/24 5.57s} 69. Re7+ {+8.91/25 6.21s} Kh8 {-10.01/25 14.71s}
70. Bf3 {+9.18/26 4.62s} Rd4 {-10.82/21 6.26s} 71. Re8+ {+9.73/27 21.50s}
Kh7 {-10.73/17 0.51s, White wins by adjudication} 1-0
```

**White pawn odds**
There are 8 positions, white has no pawn at a, b ... h.

```
Score of Stockfish 14.1 white vs Stockfish 14.1 black: 0 - 2 - 6 [0.375]
...      Stockfish 14.1 white playing White: 0 - 2 - 6  [0.375] 8
...      White vs Black: 0 - 2 - 6  [0.375] 8
Elo difference: -88.7 +/- 116.0, LOS: 7.9 %, DrawRatio: 75.0 %
8 of 8 games finished.
```

*Sample games*

```
[Event "?"]
[Site "?"]
[Date "2022.03.19"]
[Round "7"]
[White "Stockfish 14.1 white"]
[Black "Stockfish 14.1 black"]
[Result "0-1"]
[FEN "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPP1P/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1"]
[GameDuration "00:30:24"]
[PlyCount "139"]
[SetUp "1"]
[Termination "adjudication"]
[TimeControl "600+5"]

1. d4 {-1.73/26 17.70s} Nf6 {+1.80/28 36.69s} 2. c4 {-1.73/26 9.70s}
g6 {+1.93/28 6.51s} 3. Nc3 {-1.71/26 2.64s} Bg7 {+1.88/27 13.33s}
4. e4 {-1.80/27 2.49s} d6 {+1.82/26 13.24s} 5. Nge2 {-1.73/27 0.91s}
e5 {+1.86/27 43.08s} 6. d5 {-1.74/30 46.33s} a5 {+2.10/30 5.37s}
7. h4 {-1.74/29 13.76s} Na6 {+1.91/26 10.81s} 8. Ng3 {-1.61/28 2.52s}
h5 {+1.85/30 10.13s} 9. Bg5 {-1.71/27 3.26s} Bh6 {+1.73/33 83.83s}
10. Bxh6 {-1.57/33 50.24s} Rxh6 {+1.58/33 15.17s} 11. a3 {-1.50/30 11.04s}
Ng4 {+1.75/29 97.01s} 12. f3 {-1.57/29 23.06s} Ne3 {+1.86/28 0.003s}
13. Qd2 {-1.81/32 21.77s} Nxf1 {+1.72/27 5.46s} 14. Nxf1 {-1.69/28 12.44s}
Rh8 {+2.03/29 20.23s} 15. b4 {-1.78/28 4.11s} Bd7 {+2.05/29 21.99s}
16. Rb1 {-2.05/28 9.11s} Qf6 {+2.04/25 1.23s} 17. Kf2 {-1.69/26 13.52s}
Kf8 {+2.18/25 2.24s} 18. Ne3 {-1.79/27 23.61s} Bg4 {+2.24/28 52.78s}
19. Qe2 {-1.97/30 14.44s} Kg7 {+2.20/27 0.003s} 20. Nc2 {-2.25/29 50.31s}
Rhc8 {+2.16/28 0.003s} 21. Kg3 {-2.06/31 62.03s} Bd7 {+2.14/25 9.09s}
22. Qd2 {-2.14/29 15.09s} Qe7 {+2.18/26 2.35s} 23. Rh2 {-2.30/28 77.70s}
f5 {+2.37/24 20.01s} 24. Qg5 {-1.93/29 13.05s} Qxg5+ {+2.15/26 2.75s}
25. hxg5 {-2.03/29 8.72s} fxe4 {+2.05/29 2.31s} 26. Nxe4 {-2.00/30 10.28s}
Bf5 {+2.16/31 3.08s} 27. Rh4 {-1.92/30 13.14s} Rf8 {+2.18/33 17.55s}
28. Ne3 {-2.19/31 19.59s} Bxe4 {+1.89/32 0.004s} 29. Rxe4 {-2.56/34 32.46s}
Rf7 {+2.14/35 0.011s} 30. f4 {-2.57/32 14.68s} Rxf4 {+2.38/35 0.002s}
31. Rxf4 {-2.65/32 14.61s} exf4+ {+2.52/31 0.81s} 32. Kxf4 {-2.70/31 12.88s}
Rf8+ {+2.62/30 6.29s} 33. Kg3 {-2.58/30 3.91s} Rf7 {+2.73/30 14.87s}
34. Rb3 {-2.66/31 13.06s} Re7 {+2.75/32 22.47s} 35. Kf3 {-2.76/32 36.54s}
Rf7+ {+2.56/37 101.7s} 36. Kg3 {-2.68/32 13.05s} Re7 {+2.72/33 0s}
37. Kf4 {-2.87/32 21.69s} Kf7 {+2.95/30 12.94s} 38. Kf3 {-3.18/31 7.34s}
Ke8 {+2.86/36 26.58s} 39. Nc2 {-2.56/27 7.22s} Rf7+ {+2.81/33 0.67s}
40. Ke2 {-2.51/28 10.94s} Rf5 {+2.75/33 2.32s} 41. Rg3 {-2.37/27 6.94s}
Kd7 {+2.90/31 13.05s} 42. Kd2 {-3.39/31 49.69s} Rf4 {+3.20/30 11.85s}
43. Kc3 {-2.68/21 1.72s} c6 {+3.13/33 7.97s} 44. Ne3 {-3.05/28 8.59s}
axb4+ {+3.50/31 8.83s} 45. axb4 {-2.89/23 2.55s} Nc7 {+3.61/31 11.90s}
46. dxc6+ {-3.04/28 1.59s} bxc6 {+3.62/34 11.22s} 47. Ng2 {-3.07/26 7.45s}
Re4 {+3.66/33 13.18s} 48. Kd3 {-3.53/27 3.24s} d5 {+3.40/27 10.87s}
49. cxd5 {-4.02/25 2.55s} cxd5 {+3.89/27 6.26s} 50. Rf3 {-3.85/24 0.29s}
Rg4 {+3.89/22 7.75s} 51. Ne1 {-4.19/27 15.80s} Ne6 {+4.47/25 8.97s}
52. b5 {-4.01/24 7.38s} Nxg5 {+4.50/24 7.84s} 53. Rf8 {-4.60/25 5.16s}
Ne6 {+4.91/24 4.00s} 54. Rg8 {-4.44/25 0.003s} Rg3+ {+4.90/24 10.05s}
55. Kd2 {-4.43/23 5.47s} Kc7 {+4.96/25 2.73s} 56. Nd3 {-4.76/25 14.79s}
h4 {+5.39/25 7.96s} 57. Re8 {-5.18/24 0.61s} Ng5 {+5.52/25 6.93s}
58. Nb4 {-5.38/26 5.25s} h3 {+5.90/25 10.44s} 59. Nxd5+ {-5.77/23 1.54s}
Kd6 {+6.15/22 5.07s} 60. Nf6 {-6.28/24 9.68s} h2 {+7.12/24 6.28s}
61. Rh8 {-6.77/23 0s} Kc7 {+7.87/24 7.85s} 62. Nd5+ {-7.28/29 0s}
Kb7 {+8.05/23 5.33s} 63. Rxh2 {-7.66/29 0.50s} Nf3+ {+8.50/26 5.49s}
64. Ke2 {-7.68/26 0.23s} Nxh2 {+8.85/24 4.73s} 65. Kf2 {-8.60/51 7.45s}
Rg5 {+9.20/36 0s} 66. Nc3 {-8.60/24 5.19s} Kb6 {+9.45/29 5.58s}
67. Ne4 {-8.57/25 5.43s} Rg4 {+10.52/27 0.28s} 68. Nc3 {-8.89/21 5.45s}
g5 {+11.60/30 6.18s} 69. Nd5+ {-11.34/45 10.99s} Kxb5 {+59.16/30 0.52s}
70. Ke3 {-11.34/30 4.10s, Black wins by adjudication} 0-1
```

```
[Event "?"]
[Site "?"]
[Date "2022.03.19"]
[Round "8"]
[White "Stockfish 14.1 white"]
[Black "Stockfish 14.1 black"]
[Result "1/2-1/2"]
[FEN "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPP1/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1"]
[GameDuration "00:36:36"]
[PlyCount "219"]
[SetUp "1"]
[TimeControl "600+5"]

1. d4 {-0.41/27 18.79s} Nf6 {+0.55/25 18.15s} 2. c4 {-0.37/28 20.23s}
d6 {+0.50/24 8.53s} 3. Nc3 {-0.35/27 35.10s} e5 {+0.38/27 12.59s}
4. e4 {-0.56/26 12.01s} exd4 {+0.94/25 0.001s} 5. Qxd4 {-0.51/27 10.20s}
Nc6 {+0.89/23 1.45s} 6. Qd3 {-0.55/26 9.50s} Be6 {+0.79/25 32.11s}
7. f3 {-0.91/29 74.11s} Nd7 {+1.06/26 38.05s} 8. Be3 {-0.94/27 4.53s}
Nde5 {+0.90/26 17.48s} 9. Qc2 {-0.72/29 17.12s} Nxc4 {+0.89/27 20.15s}
10. Bf2 {-0.97/30 97.83s} Nb6 {+1.09/30 114.1s} 11. f4 {-1.05/31 0.009s}
Qe7 {+0.95/28 30.88s} 12. O-O-O {-1.01/28 43.94s} Nb4 {+0.93/29 14.46s}
13. Qb1 {-1.11/27 3.10s} O-O-O {+1.10/30 17.62s} 14. a3 {-1.22/29 3.64s}
Nc6 {+1.17/29 10.63s} 15. Qc2 {-1.24/27 5.09s} Kb8 {+1.25/27 11.65s}
16. Nf3 {-1.11/25 1.85s} Qe8 {+1.29/26 12.04s} 17. Bb5 {-1.31/27 15.05s}
Bd7 {+1.31/26 28.81s} 18. Kb1 {-1.05/27 6.50s} Be7 {+1.30/24 12.47s}
19. Nd5 {-1.01/27 14.47s} Rc8 {+1.17/26 15.90s} 20. Qc3 {-1.31/26 6.22s}
Nxd5 {+1.13/27 28.85s} 21. Rxd5 {-1.19/31 50.56s} a6 {+0.62/30 31.40s}
22. Bc4 {-1.28/31 6.04s} Na7 {+0.50/26 7.75s} 23. Qb3 {-0.72/24 12.62s}
c5 {+0.59/28 25.43s} 24. e5 {-0.80/27 17.41s} Ba4 {+0.68/31 16.81s}
25. Qd3 {-0.50/31 44.34s} dxe5 {+0.66/31 2.08s} 26. Re1 {-0.59/31 11.04s}
f6 {+0.86/28 0.80s} 27. fxe5 {-0.51/30 14.67s} Bc6 {+0.57/29 11.87s}
28. exf6 {-0.58/30 5.85s} gxf6 {+0.79/27 12.23s} 29. Nd2 {-0.53/31 33.56s}
Rd8 {+0.44/31 61.63s} 30. Bxc5 {-0.60/33 0.002s} Bxd5 {+0.54/29 8.88s}
31. Bxe7 {-0.46/29 15.07s} Qf7 {+0.45/30 0.001s} 32. Bxd8 {-0.44/28 9.64s}
Rxd8 {+0.53/29 0.20s} 33. Bxd5 {-0.50/31 9.88s} Rxd5 {+0.51/31 4.51s}
34. Qg3+ {-0.47/30 9.48s} Ka8 {+0.55/30 8.04s} 35. Nc4 {-0.36/30 8.69s}
Nc8 {+0.45/28 3.46s} 36. Qe3 {-0.50/30 18.31s} h5 {+0.50/33 28.86s}
37. Qe6 {-0.39/35 10.41s} Qg6+ {+0.41/33 8.57s} 38. Qe4 {-0.38/33 2.19s}
Qf7 {+0.42/36 13.75s} 39. Qe6 {-0.38/36 9.44s} Qg6+ {+0.34/35 0.006s}
40. Qe4 {-0.51/33 24.13s} Qg8 {+0.38/37 0.004s} 41. Qe8 {-0.43/34 9.94s}
Rd1+ {+0.37/34 3.86s} 42. Kc2 {-0.39/33 5.09s} Rd8 {+0.37/35 5.93s}
43. Qxg8 {-0.37/35 10.14s} Rxg8 {+0.40/36 5.34s} 44. Kd3 {-0.33/31 5.37s}
Kb8 {+0.49/31 11.21s} 45. Re6 {-0.38/33 26.16s} Rxg2 {+0.42/35 0.001s}
46. Rxf6 {-0.31/33 7.39s} Rg3+ {+0.37/33 9.39s} 47. Ke2 {-0.34/33 0.002s}
Rg4 {+0.31/30 10.68s} 48. Ne3 {-0.27/31 2.13s} Rh4 {+0.28/33 13.69s}
49. Rf8 {-0.35/29 6.50s} Rh2+ {+0.28/35 5.18s} 50. Kd3 {-0.33/33 2.48s}
Rxb2 {+0.27/34 15.50s} 51. Nc4 {-0.37/34 0s} Rb3+ {+0.27/32 9.88s}
52. Kd4 {-0.27/35 16.50s} Kc7 {+0.20/38 0.001s} 53. Rf7+ {-0.31/36 7.18s}
Kb8 {+0.19/38 5.78s} 54. Rf8 {-0.26/37 1.84s} Rb1 {+0.23/42 10.82s}
55. Rh8 {-0.28/39 0.61s} Rd1+ {+0.22/41 20.24s} 56. Kc3 {-0.25/42 0.001s}
Kc7 {+0.20/41 4.92s} 57. Rh7+ {-0.25/40 10.59s} Rd7 {+0.15/40 14.73s}
58. Rxh5 {-0.25/43 0s} Rg7 {+0.19/38 4.23s} 59. a4 {-0.25/44 10.51s}
Ne7 {+0.15/39 2.84s} 60. Kb3 {-0.25/40 5.56s} Rg3+ {+0.16/34 19.18s}
61. Ka2 {-0.24/41 7.76s} Rg7 {+0.25/32 3.28s} 62. Kb3 {-0.24/40 8.13s}
Nc6 {+0.23/36 0.003s} 63. Kc3 {-0.24/38 7.12s} Rg3+ {+0.25/31 6.09s}
64. Kb2 {-0.23/36 9.25s} Rg2+ {+0.20/35 0.001s} 65. Kc3 {-0.23/43 19.40s}
Rg3+ {+0.19/39 0.001s} 66. Kb2 {-0.23/39 17.70s} Kb8 {+0.18/43 0.002s}
67. Na5 {-0.21/36 9.72s} Nd8 {+0.18/40 0s} 68. Rh8 {-0.21/39 3.61s}
Rd3 {+0.19/41 20.31s} 69. Nc4 {-0.21/45 0.002s} Kc7 {+0.19/46 9.41s}
70. Ne5 {-0.21/42 0.001s} Rd5 {+0.18/42 6.05s} 71. Rh7+ {-0.20/42 11.05s}
Kb8 {+0.18/45 0.001s} 72. Rh8 {-0.20/39 3.70s} Kc7 {+0.16/43 6.07s}
73. Rh7+ {-0.19/38 0.003s} Kc8 {+0.15/45 6.25s} 74. Nc4 {-0.19/40 2.37s}
Kb8 {+0.15/42 6.25s} 75. Nb6 {-0.19/40 0s} Rd3 {+0.17/38 10.49s}
76. Rh8 {-0.18/38 12.21s} Kc7 {+0.15/42 0.001s} 77. Kc2 {-0.18/37 7.60s}
Rd6 {+0.15/41 24.40s} 78. Nc4 {-0.18/38 0s} Rf6 {+0.15/41 3.42s}
79. Kb2 {-0.17/37 13.96s} Rf4 {+0.15/40 3.13s} 80. Rh7+ {-0.16/40 15.91s}
Rf7 {+0.15/36 3.60s} 81. Rh6 {-0.16/35 7.62s} Rd7 {+0.14/37 0.001s}
82. Kc3 {-0.16/34 1.01s} Nc6 {+0.14/42 7.42s} 83. Rh8 {-0.16/33 4.51s}
Rd1 {+0.14/38 14.61s} 84. Kb2 {-0.14/38 0.001s} Rd8 {+0.14/34 1.95s}
85. Rh5 {-0.14/37 2.70s} Nd4 {+0.14/35 3.50s} 86. Rh7+ {-0.13/35 5.19s}
Rd7 {+0.13/35 4.30s} 87. Rh6 {-0.13/37 0.002s} Nc6 {+0.13/37 5.53s}
88. Kc3 {-0.13/32 3.40s} Kb8 {+0.13/30 1.25s} 89. Rh5 {-0.12/36 11.09s}
Rg7 {+0.13/34 0.66s} 90. Ne5 {-0.11/35 11.30s} Ne7 {+0.13/36 0s}
91. Nc4 {-0.11/34 8.99s} Ka7 {+0.12/35 0.001s} 92. Nd6 {-0.11/32 7.06s}
Rg6 {+0.13/36 4.74s} 93. Nc4 {-0.12/32 0.001s} Ng8 {+0.15/37 10.61s}
94. Kb4 {-0.18/34 0s} Nf6 {+0.14/33 4.82s} 95. Rh4 {-0.12/32 0.001s}
Rg3 {+0.19/36 7.53s} 96. Rd4 {-0.21/32 4.39s} Rg5 {+0.12/40 5.00s}
97. Rh4 {-0.13/34 0.001s} Rd5 {+0.13/33 8.25s} 98. Rh8 {-0.16/38 0.003s}
Ne4 {+0.11/36 5.17s} 99. Ra8+ {0.00/43 0.002s} Kxa8 {+0.07/33 0.77s}
100. Nb6+ {0.00/51 4.49s} Kb8 {+0.02/41 1.12s} 101. Nxd5 {0.00/55 4.73s}
Nd2 {0.00/47 0.42s} 102. Kc5 {0.00/54 4.97s} Ka7 {0.00/46 6.16s}
103. Kb4 {0.00/54 0s} b6 {0.00/55 5.38s} 104. a5 {0.00/56 2.40s}
bxa5+ {0.00/59 3.97s} 105. Kxa5 {0.00/61 2.70s} Kb7 {0.00/55 4.57s}
106. Nb4 {0.00/59 6.33s} Nc4+ {0.00/57 0.001s} 107. Ka4 {0.00/41 1.17s}
a5 {0.00/60 4.89s} 108. Kb5 {0.00/56 7.93s} axb4 {0.00/65 4.70s}
109. Kxc4 {0.00/103 1.45s} Kc6 {0.00/101 4.38s}
110. Kxb4 {0.00/112 6.59s, Draw by insufficient mating material} 1/2-1/2
```

```
[Event "?"]
[Site "?"]
[Date "2022.03.19"]
[Round "6"]
[White "Stockfish 14.1 white"]
[Black "Stockfish 14.1 black"]
[Result "0-1"]
[FEN "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPP1PP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1"]
[GameDuration "00:31:15"]
[PlyCount "143"]
[SetUp "1"]
[Termination "adjudication"]
[TimeControl "600+5"]

1. e4 {-1.62/25 16.62s} c5 {+1.64/26 18.98s} 2. Nf3 {-1.53/29 24.09s}
d6 {+1.87/27 0.003s} 3. Bc4 {-1.58/26 9.99s} e6 {+1.66/28 20.78s}
4. O-O {-1.80/29 7.43s} Nf6 {+1.77/28 4.99s} 5. Qe1 {-1.68/28 17.07s}
Be7 {+1.66/30 0s} 6. d3 {-1.83/29 41.30s} O-O {+1.78/30 0.004s}
7. Nc3 {-1.77/28 7.82s} a6 {+1.90/28 6.47s} 8. a4 {-1.86/30 29.99s}
Nc6 {+1.85/29 4.22s} 9. Qg3 {-1.88/26 8.55s} Kh8 {+1.85/27 14.26s}
10. Bd2 {-1.87/25 7.48s} Bd7 {+1.91/26 6.79s} 11. Bb3 {-1.88/29 79.83s}
Na5 {+1.80/31 0.004s} 12. Ba2 {-1.78/27 7.96s} Nc6 {+1.87/28 45.65s}
13. Kh1 {-1.97/25 9.72s} Rb8 {+1.96/28 1.03s} 14. Ne2 {-1.91/26 11.64s}
b5 {+1.88/29 10.17s} 15. axb5 {-1.87/26 2.28s} axb5 {+2.00/27 23.78s}
16. Rae1 {-1.89/28 0.004s} Bc8 {+2.07/30 84.66s} 17. Rd1 {-2.06/30 114.6s}
Ra8 {+2.19/26 18.40s} 18. Bb1 {-1.92/29 0.003s} b4 {+2.18/28 29.65s}
19. c3 {-1.87/28 8.90s} Ra1 {+2.19/27 10.22s} 20. Nf4 {-2.14/27 17.60s}
Ba6 {+2.05/29 53.11s} 21. Rfe1 {-2.00/29 0.004s} bxc3 {+2.05/25 11.38s}
22. bxc3 {-2.32/28 18.53s} Ra3 {+2.12/27 24.76s} 23. Rg1 {-2.16/28 59.20s}
Qb8 {+2.42/28 75.57s} 24. Nh3 {-2.57/28 61.90s} Nd7 {+2.40/25 13.39s}
25. Nf4 {-2.20/29 22.34s} Nde5 {+2.46/27 25.62s} 26. Bc2 {-2.58/28 0.003s}
Nxf3 {+2.53/24 8.28s} 27. gxf3 {-2.58/26 8.07s} Rg8 {+2.66/26 3.00s}
28. Nh3 {-2.58/26 11.69s} Ne5 {+2.73/27 4.85s} 29. c4 {-2.59/26 5.04s}
Bb7 {+2.67/26 12.61s} 30. Ng5 {-2.57/25 1.24s} Bxg5 {+2.48/26 21.75s}
31. Bxg5 {-2.66/27 0.001s} f5 {+3.55/27 38.42s} 32. Rge1 {-3.48/29 69.17s}
Nc6 {+3.45/26 11.06s} 33. Ra1 {-3.70/30 31.76s} Rxa1 {+3.79/27 7.53s}
34. Rxa1 {-3.80/28 4.18s} e5 {+3.79/28 6.36s} 35. Ba4 {-3.85/28 17.23s}
f4 {+3.90/29 2.34s} 36. Qg2 {-4.07/26 19.68s} Nd4 {+3.86/31 0.002s}
37. Bh4 {-3.66/27 3.58s} Bc6 {+3.74/32 11.53s} 38. Bd1 {-3.96/30 4.23s}
Qb4 {+4.08/31 17.04s} 39. Qf1 {-3.85/31 0s} Qb2 {+4.00/33 15.71s}
40. Ra6 {-3.93/33 2.08s} Qb7 {+4.07/31 38.05s} 41. Ra3 {-3.92/36 0.001s}
Be8 {+4.04/24 7.13s} 42. Bf2 {-3.75/22 5.46s} Nc6 {+4.24/28 12.09s}
43. Kg1 {-4.06/28 25.31s} h6 {+4.39/28 0.001s} 44. Ba4 {-4.18/23 4.81s}
Nb4 {+4.41/29 11.88s} 45. Bxe8 {-4.12/25 0.002s} Rxe8 {+4.50/28 10.44s}
46. h4 {-4.19/27 6.62s} Nc2 {+4.39/30 4.27s} 47. Ra2 {-4.20/29 0s}
Qb3 {+4.58/28 9.94s} 48. Ra6 {-4.44/31 16.24s} Ne3 {+4.42/36 29.91s}
49. Bxe3 {-4.75/35 0.003s} fxe3 {+4.95/35 4.98s} 50. Ra1 {-5.11/33 12.74s}
Rb8 {+5.19/35 0.28s} 51. Kh1 {-5.59/33 16.54s} Qc2 {+5.86/32 20.08s}
52. Re1 {-6.16/32 0s} Rf8 {+6.29/30 11.76s} 53. Kg1 {-6.27/31 0.002s}
Rf6 {+6.45/28 5.16s} 54. h5 {-6.44/30 0.002s} e2 {+6.62/27 6.16s}
55. Rxe2 {-6.55/29 0.001s} Qxd3 {+6.78/28 4.39s} 56. Rf2 {-6.38/30 0.001s}
Qe3 {+6.69/27 6.81s} 57. Qh3 {-6.84/29 5.74s} Kh7 {+6.96/27 0.003s}
58. Qg4 {-6.90/25 6.14s} Qc1+ {+6.93/25 0.001s} 59. Kg2 {-7.09/27 15.22s}
Qxc4 {+7.17/27 0.002s} 60. Kg3 {-7.22/23 2.98s} Qf7 {+7.70/23 8.52s}
61. Rd2 {-7.11/25 6.28s} Qb3 {+7.50/26 4.00s} 62. Rd5 {-7.60/29 13.41s}
Qb6 {+7.81/30 7.35s} 63. Rd2 {-7.80/28 4.57s} c4 {+7.89/33 4.01s}
64. Rg2 {-7.23/24 0.34s} Qa7 {+8.09/32 12.47s} 65. Rf2 {-8.02/28 3.38s}
c3 {+8.17/28 3.12s} 66. Rc2 {-8.24/30 14.03s} Qb6 {+8.42/26 4.93s}
67. Rg2 {-8.35/27 0.002s} Qb3 {+8.46/28 8.62s} 68. Kh2 {-8.42/29 0.002s}
Qf7 {+8.62/25 3.82s} 69. Rc2 {-8.62/30 14.10s} Rxf3 {+9.00/28 8.18s}
70. Kg2 {-8.86/27 2.46s} Rf4 {+9.18/27 5.41s} 71. Qg6+ {-9.28/27 5.74s}
Qxg6+ {+9.56/27 5.19s} 72. hxg6+ {-9.62/27 6.88s, Black wins by adjudication}
0-1
```

```
[Event "?"]
[Site "?"]
[Date "2022.03.19"]
[Round "2"]
[White "Stockfish 14.1 white"]
[Black "Stockfish 14.1 black"]
[Result "1/2-1/2"]
[FEN "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/P1PPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1"]
[GameDuration "00:37:58"]
[PlyCount "226"]
[SetUp "1"]
[TimeControl "600+5"]

1. c4 {-1.45/28 17.02s} g6 {+1.55/26 18.93s} 2. Nc3 {-1.56/30 0.002s}
Bg7 {+1.55/26 8.92s} 3. g3 {-1.39/27 5.82s} c5 {+1.61/26 5.74s}
4. Bg2 {-1.41/27 19.69s} Nf6 {+1.60/28 0.020s} 5. Rb1 {-1.48/28 11.94s}
Nc6 {+1.49/29 6.81s} 6. Bb2 {-1.52/28 5.57s} O-O {+1.63/29 6.71s}
7. Nd5 {-1.52/27 5.40s} Ne8 {+1.82/26 7.40s} 8. Bxg7 {-1.65/28 26.64s}
Nxg7 {+1.75/28 7.71s} 9. Nf3 {-1.75/28 8.04s} b6 {+1.75/28 15.38s}
10. O-O {-1.63/26 0.35s} Bb7 {+1.64/28 47.25s} 11. Nc3 {-1.50/28 0.002s}
d6 {+1.54/31 30.50s} 12. Nh4 {-1.38/25 20.20s} Qd7 {+1.51/29 24.40s}
13. f4 {-1.49/26 12.90s} f5 {+1.49/30 8.54s} 14. d3 {-1.53/26 9.29s}
e6 {+1.32/27 25.83s} 15. Qd2 {-1.47/25 14.73s} Rae8 {+1.39/30 12.12s}
16. Rbe1 {-1.38/25 3.74s} Nh5 {+1.46/28 5.67s} 17. e4 {-1.40/25 13.05s}
fxe4 {+1.38/29 29.47s} 18. Nxe4 {-1.37/30 54.12s} Ng7 {+1.22/34 7.17s}
19. Ng5 {-1.25/29 5.60s} Nd4 {+1.26/33 8.33s} 20. Bxb7 {-1.25/30 12.19s}
Qxb7 {+1.42/32 2.25s} 21. Nhf3 {-1.11/32 26.18s} Nxf3+ {+1.33/32 11.76s}
22. Nxf3 {-1.22/31 26.61s} e5 {+1.36/33 0.004s} 23. Ng5 {-1.30/31 14.18s}
Nf5 {+1.28/33 27.86s} 24. fxe5 {-1.20/31 0.005s} dxe5 {+1.22/31 28.53s}
25. Ne4 {-1.18/30 22.42s} Qe7 {+1.28/28 0.004s} 26. Kg2 {-1.11/30 36.18s}
Nd4 {+1.07/29 2.87s} 27. Rxf8+ {-0.95/28 14.41s} Rxf8 {+1.07/30 2.09s}
28. Rf1 {-1.05/32 25.52s} Rf5 {+1.07/30 0.002s} 29. Rf2 {-0.98/30 14.75s}
Kg7 {+0.93/31 8.41s} 30. Qe3 {-0.94/33 70.01s} h6 {+1.14/32 10.60s}
31. Nc3 {-1.11/32 20.53s} Qb7+ {+1.15/30 2.21s} 32. Nd5 {-0.99/30 26.00s}
Qf7 {+1.12/30 8.96s} 33. Nc3 {-0.89/27 15.64s} Qb7+ {+0.97/33 24.00s}
34. Nd5 {-0.83/30 12.04s} Qf7 {+0.87/33 4.65s} 35. Nc3 {-0.82/31 8.42s}
Nc6 {+0.83/31 14.01s} 36. a3 {-0.86/27 12.25s} Qf6 {+1.04/32 3.34s}
37. h3 {-0.79/31 8.93s} Nd4 {+0.88/31 17.47s} 38. Ne4 {-0.78/30 1.80s}
Qe7 {+0.85/34 18.94s} 39. Nc3 {-0.95/33 3.54s} Qf6 {+0.76/34 36.60s}
40. Ne4 {-0.77/31 16.49s} Qe7 {+0.76/34 37.38s} 41. Nc3 {-0.75/37 0.014s}
Qe6 {+0.76/33 34.10s} 42. Ne4 {-0.72/36 12.76s} Kh7 {+0.80/33 0.006s}
43. Nc3 {-0.72/32 11.85s} Kg7 {+0.76/31 2.30s} 44. Ne4 {-0.72/37 16.41s}
Qd7 {+0.75/34 28.28s} 45. Nc3 {-0.70/32 36.25s} Nc6 {+0.71/33 0.001s}
46. Qe4 {-0.70/31 17.23s} Qe6 {+0.71/36 13.18s} 47. Rf3 {-0.70/29 11.04s}
Nd8 {+0.71/35 0.002s} 48. Rf2 {-0.68/31 28.10s} Nc6 {+0.75/35 0.001s}
49. Rf3 {-0.70/31 11.80s} h5 {+0.70/34 50.56s} 50. Qe3 {-0.76/35 0.003s}
Qf7 {+0.74/34 10.78s} 51. Ne4 {-0.63/35 18.86s} Qe7 {+0.70/32 12.67s}
52. Nc3 {-0.69/29 11.52s} Qf6 {+0.70/33 1.50s} 53. Qe4 {-0.64/32 30.84s}
Kh6 {+0.70/33 12.92s} 54. Qe3+ {-0.63/32 11.23s} Kg7 {+0.70/36 5.47s}
55. Nd5 {-0.62/31 0.002s} Qd6 {+0.70/39 9.01s} 56. Qe4 {-0.65/34 6.11s}
Qf8 {+0.70/38 6.24s} 57. Nc3 {-0.62/31 5.56s} Qf6 {+0.69/37 19.31s}
58. Qd5 {-0.61/34 0.005s} Rxf3 {+0.69/36 14.45s} 59. Qxf3 {-0.61/36 0.001s}
Nd4 {+0.68/34 13.55s} 60. Qe3 {-0.60/34 0.14s} Kh7 {+0.68/35 11.68s}
61. Ne4 {-0.56/31 8.00s} Qf5 {+0.62/34 20.41s} 62. a4 {-0.54/36 0.002s}
Kg7 {+0.57/33 11.14s} 63. Nd6 {-0.53/36 0.006s} Qe6 {+0.55/32 11.00s}
64. Ne4 {-0.51/33 0.073s} Qe7 {+0.49/34 11.36s} 65. Qe1 {-0.68/36 29.50s}
Qd7 {+0.49/34 16.13s} 66. Qe3 {-0.51/29 3.96s} Qf5 {+0.48/31 5.74s}
67. Nd6 {-0.51/37 6.69s} Qe6 {+0.44/32 3.13s} 68. Ne4 {-0.51/36 2.00s}
Qe7 {+0.43/35 8.00s} 69. Qe1 {-0.50/33 1.96s} Qd7 {+0.43/31 6.36s}
70. Qe3 {-0.50/35 1.45s} Qf7 {+0.38/32 23.83s} 71. Nc3 {-0.50/37 0.001s}
Qf5 {+0.41/37 18.53s} 72. Ne4 {-0.50/33 0.006s} Nc2 {+0.38/33 9.08s}
73. Qe2 {-0.51/33 8.45s} Nb4 {+0.38/34 0.001s} 74. Nd6 {-0.50/33 7.69s}
Qe6 {+0.38/34 0.007s} 75. Ne4 {-0.50/33 7.21s} Qf5 {+0.40/33 4.74s}
76. Nd6 {-0.47/31 8.87s} Qe6 {+0.42/34 0.008s} 77. Ne4 {-0.46/34 9.23s}
Qe7 {+0.38/35 0.007s} 78. Qe3 {-0.47/35 5.75s} Qf8 {+0.37/33 0.68s}
79. Qg5 {-0.60/30 7.07s} Nc6 {+0.37/37 8.16s} 80. Qe3 {-0.50/32 1.56s}
Nd4 {+0.41/35 17.46s} 81. Ng5 {-0.36/31 0.001s} Qf6 {+0.73/27 7.56s}
82. Nf3 {-0.32/28 5.66s} Qf5 {+0.28/36 33.44s} 83. Nh4 {-0.12/36 0.002s}
Qf6 {+0.20/27 1.41s} 84. Nf3 {-0.12/29 8.34s} Qf5 {+0.19/33 0.001s}
85. Nh4 {-0.12/34 6.39s} Qf7 {+0.19/37 0.002s} 86. Nf3 {-0.05/29 4.12s}
Qf6 {+0.10/34 4.25s} 87. Qe4 {-0.02/33 2.43s} Qxf3+ {0.00/32 3.09s}
88. Qxf3 {0.00/36 3.53s} Nxf3 {0.00/38 0.003s} 89. Kxf3 {0.00/43 7.35s}
Kf6 {0.00/41 0.001s} 90. Ke4 {0.00/43 7.26s} Ke6 {0.00/43 5.35s}
91. Ke3 {0.00/41 1.03s} Kf5 {0.00/46 4.95s} 92. Kf3 {0.00/45 6.35s}
a5 {0.00/49 0.002s} 93. Ke3 {0.00/49 5.09s} Ke6 {0.00/43 0.15s}
94. Ke4 {0.00/49 6.14s} Kf6 {0.00/46 2.49s} 95. Kd5 {0.00/49 38.93s}
Kf5 {0.00/43 6.66s} 96. Kc6 {0.00/45 0.007s} h4 {0.00/44 9.09s}
97. gxh4 {0.00/47 0.002s} Kf4 {0.00/45 5.31s} 98. Kxb6 {0.00/46 0.010s}
Ke3 {0.00/46 7.39s} 99. Kxc5 {0.00/46 0.003s} Kxd3 {0.00/47 6.64s}
100. Kb5 {0.00/46 0.59s} e4 {0.00/46 4.52s} 101. c5 {0.00/46 3.82s}
e3 {0.00/45 2.42s} 102. c6 {0.00/47 2.87s} e2 {0.00/46 8.33s}
103. c7 {0.00/49 0.001s} e1=Q {0.00/47 5.50s} 104. c8=Q {0.00/49 1.18s}
Qb4+ {0.00/45 10.98s} 105. Ka6 {0.00/50 3.06s} Qxa4 {0.00/47 1.97s}
106. Qd8+ {0.00/51 6.65s} Qd4 {0.00/47 0.005s} 107. Qxa5 {0.00/52 6.50s}
Qxh4 {0.00/49 0.31s} 108. Qa3+ {0.00/48 6.94s} Ke2 {0.00/50 0.001s}
109. Qb2+ {0.00/48 12.36s} Kf3 {0.00/51 6.44s} 110. Qc3+ {0.00/46 0.50s}
Kg2 {0.00/54 7.13s} 111. Qc2+ {0.00/49 0.003s} Kxh3 {0.00/52 6.15s}
112. Qxg6 {0.00/49 2.89s} Qg4 {0.00/53 5.62s} 113. Qxg4+ {0.00/72 42.85s}
Kxg4 {0.00/102 5.51s, Draw by insufficient mating material} 1/2-1/2
```

Comment: If *Black* lacks a pawn, then Black has given White odds of pawn *and move*. The question asked about pawn odds, i.e. where *White* lacks a pawn. What results do you have for these setups?

Comment: @RosieF the question explicitly asks about both White and Black giving pawn odds. And both are provided here.

Comment: Curious that in the one drawn game shown (White -Ph2) 
the defender actually sacrificed a second pawn before reaching
a drawn pawn-down ending.

Comment: @ferdy Hi, could you post the game when white has the b pawn missing?

Comment: @edit_profile requested game added.

Comment: interesting games from Stockfish!

Answer (score 3):

"Is there any evidence"? No, not unless you count anecdotes as evidence. The analysis is still intractable at this stage, and vastly fewer resources are redirected to odds analysis than to regular chess analysis.

While it is difficult to cite a negative, here are [some comments from another site](https://www.quora.com/Has-chess-been-solved-with-different-odds-definitively-For-example-pawn-odds-or-knight-odds-or-even-queen-odds) (note the question quoted is the stronger "solved", but the answer addresses the question at hand):

> ### Has chess been solved with different odds, definitively? For example pawn odds or knight odds or even queen odds?

> Has anyone wasted their time trying to prove this? No. Why should they? It is clear that a piece, especially a Queen odds results in a loss. Think computers if you will. Try being a piece down and play the very best computer moves - you lose - every single time. To not lose requires a non optimal move by the side with the material.

> As to a pawn odds game. It is not so clear. Clearly the strategy would be to play to eliminate all pawns followed by pieces and hope to exchange the last minor piece for the extra and final pawn. But that ignores that the extra pawn is also an offensive weapon and more weapons means more threats. However since gambits involve the sac of a pawn for a lead in development one can never be certain the extra pawn wins as it depends on which pawn and whether the pawn removed results in a lead in development sufficient to combat the material deficit.

Comment: +1 but presumably it's possible to run engine matches at pawn odds. If most games are drawn, that would be evidence.

Comment: @Allure Running an engine from pawn-odds start to conclusion draw/loss is not currently possible. See current tablebases, which can only handle seven pieces.

Comment: @Allure I did that experiment right now by removing h2 (white's) pawn in the initial position, thus giving black an advantage of -0.4, but as both the sides played the best move in the knowledge of stockfish 14.1 , the advantage was -8  by move 48 , and it eventually led to black's victory. So should be the case with +1 advantage for white too.

Comment: I don't mean *solving* the game and proving that the result must be ___. I mean playing, say, 10k games of the engine itself. If the result of that is, say, +10 =950 -40, then we can say there's good evidence it's drawn.

Comment: @AyushDwi Thanks but it's only one game though. Presumably there'd need to be more to get past small sample size effects. Also, what time control did you use?

Comment: @Allure But let us emphasis on the point that the moves were best "in the knowlege of sf" and definately there are scopes for its improvement in the future.

Comment: @Allure Indeed.

Comment: Ah, well yeah "games between machines that use limited analysis" offer little in the way of evidence as to wether the starting position is actually drawn or not, given the nature of the limits on the analysis.

Comment: A good AI is trained by using sample data from large numbers of actual human-played games.  Since every major FIDE game has been recorded for decades, there's a huge pool of data to analyze.  There are *far* fewer games starting from non-standard positions available to analyze.  So the AIs (like humans) are not well trained on these.  This is one of the draws of e.g. Chess960 - the standard starting position has been analyzed to death for centuries, so most openings are played from memory.  Other starting positions have not, so it's a very different challenge.  Pawn odds games are similar.

Comment: @Darrel Hoffman I have always understood that the f-pawn was chosen as the handicap because it gave the most severe disadvantage, and also  the absence of a different Pawn might actually give some compensation in development. When such games were common, there seem to have been some heuristics on the best policy for White to take. For example, in the games between Bird and Morphy, Bird went for early (possibly premature) attacks, that stil demanded very precise defence from Morphy. A modern computer, whether
based on human experience or deep learning, would be unable to make such judgements.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman *A good AI is trained by using sample data from large numbers of actual human-played games.* These days the best engines don't rely on human-played games for training at all - Leela relies completely on self-play, and Stockfish uses Leela's eval. Not sure what Komodo does.

Comment: @Allure They're still almost exclusively trained on the standard starting position though, aren't they?

Answer (score 2):

FEN: rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPP1PP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1 (white without f2 pawn)

Stockfish_22030820_x64_avx2: NNUE evaluation using nn-6877cd24400e.nnue enabled

61/65 **267,302,583k -1.95**

e2-e4 e7-e6 Ng1-f3 d7-d5 e4xd5 e6xd5 d2-d4 Bf8-e7 Nb1-c3 Ng8-f6 Bf1-d3 O-O O-O c7-c5 d4xc5 Be7xc5+ Kg1-h1 h7-h6 Bc1-f4 Nb8-c6 Bf4-g3 Rf8-e8 Bg3-h4 Bc8-e6 Qd1-d2 Bc5-e7 Bh4-f2 a7-a6 Nf3-d4 Nf6-g4 Nd4xe6 f7xe6 Bf2-g1 Be7-d6 Bd3-e2 Nc6-e5 Ra1-d1 Ng4-f6 Bg1-f2 Bd6-c7 Qd2-e1 Qd8-d7 Bf2-d4 Re8-f8 b2-b4 Ra8-d8 b4-b5 Qd7-d6 a2-a4 Rd8-e8 Qe1-g3 Nf6-d7 b5xa6 b7xa6

This is strong evidence that white is lost without the f2 pawn. Similar evidence points to a loss without the g2 and b2 pawns.

Bonus edit: When black gives pawn odds, black is lost. Stockfish's evaluation rises to +2.0 very quickly regardless of the pawn black gives up.